# How do I filter NAs using DataFramesMeta.jl?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have the following `@where` clause in my pipeline

```
@where(:correct .!= "", !isna.(:expression_size))
```

that is returning the following warning

```
WARNING: !(B::BitArray) is deprecated, use .!(B) instead.
Stacktrace:
 [1] depwarn(::String, ::Symbol) at ./deprecated.jl:70
 [2] !(::BitArray{1}) at ./deprecated.jl:57
 [3] ##1423 at /Users/morpheu5/.julia/v0.6/DataFramesMeta/src/DataFramesMeta.jl:70 [inlined]
 [4] (::##455#458)(::DataFrames.DataFrame) at /Users/morpheu5/.julia/v0.6/DataFramesMeta/src/DataFramesMeta.jl:72
 [5] where(::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::##455#458) at /Users/morpheu5/.julia/v0.6/DataFramesMeta/src/DataFramesMeta.jl:194
 [6] include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:515
 [7] include_string(::Module, ::String, ::String) at /Users/morpheu5/.julia/v0.6/Compat/src/Compat.jl:478
 [8] execute_request(::ZMQ.Socket, ::IJulia.Msg) at /Users/morpheu5/.julia/v0.6/IJulia/src/execute_request.jl:154
 [9] eventloop(::ZMQ.Socket) at /Users/morpheu5/.julia/v0.6/IJulia/src/eventloop.jl:8
 [10] (::IJulia.##14#17)() at ./task.jl:335
while loading In[71], in expression starting on line 2
```

If I use the element-wise version, as suggested, I get a proper error

```
@where(:correct .!= "", .!isna.(:expression_size))

MethodError: no method matching getindex(::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::DataArrays.DataArray{Any,1}, ::Colon)
```

It seems that Julia is a bit confused about NAs in general, by what I've seen on the Internet, but this feel like it should work (and in fact it does in the first case, except for that horrible warning that pollutes my Jupyter notebook :)

**EDIT** If I run the `!isna.` variant on the REPL, I get no warning, and the thing works as expected.

Comment: I see you're running quite a lot of data manipulation code - have you given Query.jl a spin?

Comment: I have but I keep having to go back and forth between packages to get anything done. I found that I can't do everything in Query.jl, unfortunately.

Comment: OK - things are going to look up really soon with new releases of the data packages, then things should hopefully get easier.

Comment: I sure hope so, this thing is giving me such nightmares that I'm considering going for python - and avoiding python and R was among my main reasons for picking Julia :)

Comment: I think everybody sympathizes - everyone know that the current state of the data-workflow is the weakest element of current julia, not because of lack of work, but because it's taken a long time to devise an implementation that will keep the speed, flexibility and type-stability of julia while allowing for missing values. Noone can count the number of hours that people have put into re-implementing functionality. The good news is that there's definitely light at the end of the tunnel now; I think even in a few months everything will be much better.

Comment: The new DataFrames release with the new `missing` value type etc. should come out within days.

Comment: I think right now I'd really appreciate a way of running a row-wise reduce on a DataFrame so that I can simplify the current reduce function I am running by running it over groups. I have had to devise a pretty convoluted workflow just because of this, and other delightful quirks of my data -- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460140/can-i-group-by-an-array-of-dictionaries-in-julia), for example.

Comment: Do you think you could find something useful in this post: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/various-by-group-strategies-compared/6594 ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll certainly look into that :)

Answer (score 0):

As of DataFramesMeta v0.11.0, `@where` is called `@subset` instead. Since the question said "in my pipeline", I'll write it as part of an `@chain` block.

Initialize a DataFrame:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(correct = ["yes", "yep", "", "yeah", ""], expression_size = [9, missing, 42, 100, missing], nums = 1:5)
5×3 DataFrame
 Row │ correct  expression_size  nums  
     │ String   Int64?           Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1 │ yes                    9      1
   2 │ yep              missing      2
   3 │                       42      3
   4 │ yeah                 100      4
   5 │                  missing      5
```

Using `@subset` only:

```
julia> @chain df begin
         @subset(:correct .!= "", (!ismissing).(:expression_size))
       end
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ correct  expression_size  nums  
     │ String   Int64?           Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1 │ yes                    9      1
   2 │ yeah                 100      4
```

Using `@byrow` within `@subset`:

```
julia> @chain df begin
         @subset begin 
           @byrow !isempty(:correct)
           @byrow !ismissing(:expression_size)
         end
       end
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ correct  expression_size  nums  
     │ String   Int64?           Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1 │ yes                    9      1
   2 │ yeah                 100      4
```

Another alternative is using the `filter` method instead:

```
julia> @chain df begin 
         filter((row -> !isempty(row.correct) && !ismissing(row.expression_size)), _)
       end
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ correct  expression_size  nums  
     │ String   Int64?           Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1 │ yes                    9      1
   2 │ yeah                 100      4
```

(`filter` requires an `_` due to its argument order, and in general doesn't conform to the other DataFrames(Meta) manipulation functions' interface.)

In all three cases, `expression_size` can be turned into a pure `Int64` column by adding a

```
disallowmissing(:expression_size)
```

line to the `@chain` block at the end.