# Can I "group by" an array of dictionaries in Julia?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, dataframe, julia, reduce

I'm reading in an array from a JSON file because I need to perform a reduce on it before turning it into a `DataFrame` for further manipulation. For the sake of argument, let's say this is it

```
a = [Dict("A" => 1, "B" => 1, "C" => "a")
     Dict("A" => 1, "B" => 2, "C" => "b")
     Dict("A" => 2, "B" => 1, "C" => "b")
     Dict("A" => 2, "B" => 2, "C" => "a")]
```

Now, the reduce I'm performing would be greatly simplified if I could group the array by one or more keys (say, A and C), perform a simpler reduce on each group, and recombine the rows later into a larger array of `Dict`s that I can then easily turn into a `DataFrame`.

One solution would be to turn this into a `DataFrame`, split it into groups, turn individual groups into matrices, do the reduce (with some difficulty, because now I've lost the ability to refer to elements by their name), turn the reduced matrices back into `(Sub?)DataFrame`s (with some more difficulty because names), and hope it all comes together nicely into one giant `DataFrame`.

Any easier and/or more practical way of doing this?

**EDIT** Before somebody suggests I look at `Query.jl`, the reduce I'm running returns an array, with fewer rows because I'm squashing certain pairs of subsequent rows. If I can do such a thing with `Query.jl`, could somebody hint at how, because the documentation isn't exactly clear on how to "aggregate" with anything that doesn't return a single value. Example:

```
 A   B   C
-----------
 1       a
 2   1   a
 3       b
 4   2   b
```

should group by "C" and turn that table into something like

```
 A   B   C
-----------
 1   1   a
 3   2   b
```

To clarify, the reduce is working, I only want to simplify it by not having to check if a row belongs to the same group of the previous row before doing the squashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still experimental, but [`SplitApplyCombine.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaData/SplitApplyCombine.jl) might do the trick.  You can group arbitrary iterables using any key function you want, and get a key -> group dict out at the end.

```
julia> ## Pkg.clone("https://github.com/JuliaData/SplitApplyCombine.jl.git")

julia> using SplitApplyCombine

julia> group(x->x["C"], a)
Dict{Any,Array{Dict{String,Any},1}} with 2 entries:
  "b" => Dict{String,Any}[Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("B", 2),Pair{String,Any}("A", 1),Pair{String,Any}("C", "b")), Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("…
  "a" => Dict{String,Any}[Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("B", 1),Pair{String,Any}("A", 1),Pair{String,Any}("C", "a")), Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("…
```

Then you can use standard `[map]reduce` operations (here using the SAC `@_` macro for piping):

```
julia> @_ a |> group(x->x["C"], _) |> values(_) |> reduce(vcat, _)
4-element Array{Dict{String,Any},1}:
 Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("B", 2),Pair{String,Any}("A", 1),Pair{String,Any}("C", "b"))
 Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("B", 1),Pair{String,Any}("A", 2),Pair{String,Any}("C", "b"))
 Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("B", 1),Pair{String,Any}("A", 1),Pair{String,Any}("C", "a"))
 Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("B", 2),Pair{String,Any}("A", 2),Pair{String,Any}("C", "a"))
```